# JsonResult has no name, how do I access the values

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a linq query in my controller that returns values from the database in JSON format. However The JSON object has no name so I tried a couple things but everything returns undefined.

My JSON object looks like:

`Object {UserId: 4, UserName: "John", UserPassword: "Password"}`

## Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(string searchString, string searchPassword)
{

    var user = (from u in db.Users where u.UserName.Equals(searchString) && u.UserPassword.Equals(searchPassword) select u).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(user);
}
```

## Ajax

```
$('#test2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var user = "John";
    var userpass = "Password";

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Users")",
        data: { "searchString": user, "searchPassword": userpass },
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
            var results = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                results[data[i]["Key"]] = data[i]["Value"];
            }
            alert((result.UserName));
            alert((result.UserPassword));
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    })
})
```

The alerts come up with just `undefined`

Comment: You result JSON is a single object. You are trying to extract the information form the result as though it was an array.

Comment: Yeah I tried scavenging some code from other questions but to no avail. Could you tell me how to modify it for my use?

Comment: try console.log(data) as the first line in your success function.  that will show you the structure you're dealing with.

Comment: That seems to just log me back my JSON object : `Object {UserId: 4, UserName: "John", UserPassword: "Password"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the object by just using the properties from your C# object. So in your ajax success function, just use data.UserId or data.UserName

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to accept if this was the answer, it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your ajax success

```
 success: function (data) {
            var results = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                result.push(data[i].UserId +" "+ data[i].UserName);
            }
            alert(result);
        }
```